# How angular2 set pagination params with spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, angular, pagination

I have a spring mvc backend.

a pagination rest controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/blog", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<Blog> getEntryByPageable(@PageableDefault(value = 15, sort = { "id" }, direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) 
    Pageable pageable) {
    return blogRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

in angular2 http get ,

```
const url='/blog'
 this.http.get(url, xx)
.subscribe(e=>{
console.log(e);
}
}
```

how to set the pagination query params?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UrlSearchParams` then add it to the request config options, under the `search` property

```
import { UrlSearchParams } from '@angualar/http'

let params = new UrlSearchParams();
params.set('page', '1');
params.set('size', '5');
http.get(url, { search: params })
```

This will set the params as the querystring.

Comment: how to add sort param?

Comment: Just use `sort` and the property name to sort by